# Create one xsd for two xml files

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have two xml files and I need to create one xsd for both. This is the first time I am dealing with xml files. How can I create one xsd for both xml files and validate that they are correct?

My first xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<specification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<DATA>
 <Id>S2</Id>
  <Name>sai</Name>
 <Service>manufaturer</Service>
  <ref_complete_customer path="/work/bsr.xml"/>
  <ref_complete_customer path="/work/srr.xml"/>
 <Service_Customers>
  <Customer Id="bs"/>
 </Service_Customers>     
 <Service_Suppliers>
     <Supplier Id="r"/>
    <Supplier Id="b"/> 
    <Supplier Id="L"/>
 </Service_Suppliers>
 </DATA>
 </specification>
```

My second xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <universitylist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <university>
 <refstr>bdvl_te_skrm_stc</refstr>
 <ref_complete_customer path="/work/bsr.xml"/>
 <Code>A0f11478</Code>
 <Area>sku</Area>
 <started>1987</started>
 <branch>
  <electronics>
    <students Nr="120" ece="ab">
    <student Name="svr" year="2010" rank="3"/>
    <student Name="bvr" year="2010" rank="1"/>
    </students>
  </electronics>
 </branch>
 <semister>
    <semister num="3"/>
 </semister>
 <address>
   1.address of student
  <extrainfo>
  </extrainfo>
 </address>
 </university>
</universitylist>
```

This is my approch

```
  specification.xsd for frist file.
 universitylist.xsd for second file.
```

combined xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 

<xs:include schemaLocation="specification.xsd" />
<xs:include schemaLocation="universitylist.xsd" />

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: there is no link between two xml files..

Comment: @SivaCharan can you help me how to create link between two xml files.

Comment: An XSD file specifies a set of rules governing the structure of XML.  One thing it does not do is uniquely specify the top-level element, so you can just create rules for the `specification` schema and the `universitylist` schema and place them into the same XSD.

Comment: If you don't need to specify the schemas manually but just want a schema that two or more XML files will conform to, you may be interested in generating it through [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want a single schema that describes both document instances, since they seem completely unrelated. But the fact that they are unrelated makes it trivial - you just combine the two XSDs. For example, if you currently have a.xsd and b.xsd, then you can create a new c.xsd that simply does an xs:include on both of these.

Comment: I tried as you said and I written separate xsd for two xml files and created new xsd with those two. can have a look at my approach. I am new to xml so I am asking my approach is correct or not.I posted my approach in question.

Comment: @user1058595 As mr. Kay has indicated, you **could** use that approach and it will work. But it just seems pointless. The XML files seem completely unrelated. It's possible you want to validate XML files that are received and which may have a number of syntaxes using one schema, but in that case it's still more advisable to have some kind of syntax detection and select the appropriate schema. To actually process the XML after validation, something similar would need to happen anyway.

Comment: @G_H "Some kind of syntax detection and select the appropriate schema" means what should I do now.

Comment: @user1058595 It all really depends on how you're using the XML and validation. Is it called within a program you're making? Schema-aware XSLT transform? Manual validation? Data binding? Your use-case will determine what's the best approach and what would/wouldn't work.

Comment: @G_H hi I am validating xml files using XMLPAD, can you tel me how to this problem, I have two xsd files for two different xml files, I want to create one xsd for both files, you said I need to sysntax that one xsd could fallow only this xml file,like that. I am not able to solve this can help me with some example. You know my problem I posted that one as second question and now I deleted that one.